# How does dependencies affect unlocked packages?

Tags: salesforcedx

- What happens behind the scenes when creating an unlocked package, and especially what is the difference when adding dependencies?
- Are the dependent packages included in the package somehow, or just required to be installed in the org beforehand?
- Will one get an error if trying to install an unlocked package if the dependent package is missing?
- How about versioning of the dependent packages, especially App Store packages?

Comment: I've rewritten the question. Didn't mean for it to be just "why so slow", but actually to learn some of what's under the hood to better understand and get things up and running. I noticed that building packages became 10 minutes slower after adding a dependency, so I'd like to find out more about that. Not because I can't wait, but because there are other problems later in the process, and more understanding could maybe help solve it.

Comment: These are all covered in the various articles on [installing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_apps.htm), [converting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=convert_to_managed_package.htm), and [uninstalling](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=distribution_uninstalling_packages.htm) packages, plus the  [cli](https://engineering.salesforce.com/open-sourcing-oclif-the-cli-framework-that-powers-our-clis-21fbda99d33a) and [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/10/winter-18-sample-apps-northern-trail-outfitters-dreamhouse-dreaminvest.html) blog posts.